# EPS 'file not found'

Tags: eps, revtex

I'm using the MiKTeX distribution with TeXStudio IDE. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{Nice Title}
\maketitle
Hello world.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myEPSfile}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I use LaTeX, then I get the `TeX capacity exceeded` error. If I use LuaLaTeX, then I get a `file not found` error. If I include the eps extension then I get `unknown graphics extension` error. You can download my eps file [from here](http://www.megafileupload.com/nhK2/myEPSfile.eps), if interested.

Note: Using pdfLaTeX with `epstopdf` package works, but the publisher do not want that route.

Comment: there are external programs to convert an `.eps` file to `.pdf` and that is possibly your best approach, unless the publisher explicitly requires an `.eps` file.  the conversion only needs to be done once, unless the content of the figure changes.

Comment: The publisher wants .eps files along with the .tex file, nothing else.

Comment: if you only have to deliver the `.tex` and `.eps` files, do you have to tell the publisher that you used pdflatex with `epstopdf` to make sure it gives the output you want?  ignoring that possibility, the next step is to figure out why you get `tex capacity exceeded`.  i'd look first at the line endings in the file; was this file created on the same computer you're running tex on?  if it was created on a mac or linux system, then the line endings may be incompatible.  (someone else should give instructions if this is the case.)

Comment: Am getting these errors even with the MWE above, which basically has two words. Everything is on Windows.

The publisher will use their own LaTeX engine to render the PDF, so if it doesn't work in my computer am afraid it might not on theirs.

Comment: publishers (should) have people who know how to handle such problems.  (disclosure: i work for ams, which does have such staff.)  the problem is clearly the `.eps` file.  it has to be read to determine the bounding box.  try entering the bounding box info as an argument to the `\includegraphics` statement; that may allow latex to avoid trying to read the file. i don't really know; this is just a guess, but it's worth a try.  (you can find that info at the top of the `.eps` file.)

Comment: I might be able to help you, but I can't download the `eps` file (the 'free user' link just reloads the same page). Can you make it available from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem really is in the eps files. I was using Igor Pro, a data analysis software, to produce the files. Its manual states the following:

> Some poorly written applications are confused by the screen preview.
>   They ignore the EPS rules and use the size of the preview image rather
>   than the PostScript bounding box, resulting in improper recreation of
>   the EPS graphic. If you get unsatisfactory results, try using Igor’s
>   Suppress Preview option. The resulting EPS will display as a plain box
>   in most programs but will print correctly.

After removing that option everything seems fine now, although I have to use XeLaTeX and not LaTeX itself.

Comment: Note you are most likely not using LaTeX it self, but rather pdflatex which does not support EPS. You'll probably need to ask your editor to use latex and not pdflatex